# SwiftUI, @Published with ForEach not updating my View

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I'm trying to make a list of products. In GetProducts class, I'm getting the data from Firebase Dtabase. Then I use @Published for use this products in another struct. But in my product list, view is not updating.

Here is the simplified GetProducts class;

```
import Combine
import FirebaseDatabase

class GetProducts: ObservableObject {

private let database = Database.database().reference()

//Shared list
@Published var productList: [String] = []

//Reading the products from Firebase Database
func getProducts() {
    database.child("Products").child("Category1").child("name").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? String else {
            return
        }
        print("Value: \(value)")
        self.productList.append(value)
    })
}

}
```

In print everything seems fine, I got the data. And the View;

```
struct ProductsView: View {

@ObservedObject var products = GetProducts()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< products.productList.count, id: \.self) { product in
                NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetails()) {
                    Text("\(products.productList[product])")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Product List"))
    }
}
}
```

And I'm calling the getProducts function in the first view (ContentView);

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var products = GetProducts()
@State var selected = 0

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selected) {
        ProductsView()
            .tabItem {
                if self.selected == 0 {
                    Image(systemName: "tray.and.arrow.down")
                    Text("Products")
                }else {
                    Image(systemName: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill")
                    Text("Products")
                }
            }.tag(0)
        AddNewProductView()
            .tabItem {
                if self.selected == 1 {
                    Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.up")
                    Text("Add Product")
                }else {
                    Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.up.fill")
                    Text("Add Product")
                }
            }.tag(1)
    }.onAppear(perform: products.getProducts)
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `getProducts()` (the function, not the type of the same name)?

Comment: In the ContentView. I edited the question now @jnpdx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different instances of `GetProducts`, which don't share data with each other.  Instead of making a new one in `ProductsView`, pass it as a dependency:

```
struct ProductsView: View {

@ObservedObject var products : GetProducts
```

```
AddNewProductView(products: products)
```

Also worth noting that you may run into problems doing `ForEach` with just the range like you have it. I recommend you switch to:

```
ForEach(products.productList, id: \.self) { product in
                NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetails()) {
                    Text("\(product)")
                }
            }
```